# What is the best way to give a C# auto-property an initial value?

Tags: c#, constructor, getter, setter, automatic-properties

How do you give a C# auto-property an initial value?

I either use the constructor, or revert to the old syntax.

**Using the Constructor:**

```
class Person 
{
    public Person()
    {
        Name = "Initial Name";
    }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**Using normal property syntax**  (with an initial value)

```
private string name = "Initial Name";
public string Name 
{
    get 
    {
        return name;
    }
    set
    {
        name = value;
    }
}
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2948, accepted):

In C# 5 and earlier, to give auto implemented properties an initial value, you have to do it in a constructor.

Since [C# 6.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-version-history#c-version-60), you can specify initial value in-line. The syntax is:

```
public int X { get; set; } = x; // C# 6 or higher
```

[`DefaultValueAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.defaultvalueattribute?view=netframework-4.8) is intended to be used by the VS designer (or any other consumer) to specify a default value, not an initial value. (Even if in designed object, initial value is the default value).

At compile time `DefaultValueAttribute` will not impact the generated IL and it will not be read to initialize the property to that value (see [DefaultValue attribute is not working with my Auto Property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1980520/defaultvalue-attribute-is-not-working-with-my-auto-property)).

Example of attributes that impact the IL are [`ThreadStaticAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threadstaticattribute?view=netframework-4.8), [`CallerMemberNameAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute?view=netframework-4.8), ...

Comment: It's worth to note that this works also for getter-only properties: `public int X { get; } = x;`

Comment: What about setter only?

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes your example can be a readonly property as well `public int X => x;`

Comment: @Narish,: Your version only works if `x` is a constant or literal or a read-only field. Otherwise it will return the current, possibly changing value of `x` at each call. In my version, `x` could be a static read-write field and it will always return the same value, even if the field changes.

Comment: @ATL_DEV, a setter only property cannot be an auto property.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes fair point, yes there is a subtle distinction as readonly property is a getter to the variable `x`, while your version is a getter to the init value which in this case is `x`. I think for a readonly property as simplistic as this then, more than likely, `x` should have some enforcement around it such that it is constant or readonly. But I do see how this can shoot you in the foot

Comment: @Narish. To be precise: my property returns the value of the hidden backing field that will be initialized with `x`.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes pause, what you just described is how I understand a readonly property. So for `private int _x = 1;`, when we say `public int X => _x` we are saying "read the value of _x". If its `private readonly _x = 1;` we are in the clear, but if its not readonly, then we fall victim to the issue you specify. Now for `public int X { get; } = _x;` which is saying "init this property to _x, which is 1" and since _x is int, a **value type**, there should be no reference copy here and its defacto `public int X { get; } = 1`

Comment: So what I'm essentially asking here is, really for `public int X { get; } = x;` that backing field should no longer be involved after initialization, since its a value type. If it were a reference type, that's now a different discussion

Comment: See: https://sharplab.io/#gist:a8cf845d585e24e4d4d1a5021ed863ad. The right panel shows the decompiled IL code. This is what C# really does.

Answer (score 331):

**C# 6** :

With C# 6 you can initialize auto-properties directly (finally!), there are now other answers that describe that.

**C# 5 and below**:

Though the intended use of the attribute is not to actually set the values of the properties, you can use reflection to always set them anyway...

```
public class DefaultValuesTest
{    
    public DefaultValuesTest()
    {               
        foreach (PropertyDescriptor property in TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(this))
        {
            DefaultValueAttribute myAttribute = (DefaultValueAttribute)property.Attributes[typeof(DefaultValueAttribute)];

            if (myAttribute != null)
            {
                property.SetValue(this, myAttribute.Value);
            }
        }
    }

    public void DoTest()
    {
        var db = DefaultValueBool;
        var ds = DefaultValueString;
        var di = DefaultValueInt;
    }


    [System.ComponentModel.DefaultValue(true)]
    public bool DefaultValueBool { get; set; }

    [System.ComponentModel.DefaultValue("Good")]
    public string DefaultValueString { get; set; }

    [System.ComponentModel.DefaultValue(27)]
    public int DefaultValueInt { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Voting -1: At best, it looks subjectively looks a little neater than initializing in the constructor. This comes at the cost of confusing developers new to the codebase, worse performance, semantically changing the meaning of a built in attribute, only allowing constants, default values being hard to spot among multiple attributes, having to remember to run this in every constructor overload, and having the possibility of having default values defined in both the attribute and the constructor.

Comment: I would prefer using an ordinary property (instead of an auto property) where I could set the default value on the private variable, or initialize the property in the constructor, before I resorted to Reflection.

Answer (score 215):

When you inline an initial value for a variable it will be done implicitly in the constructor anyway.

I would argue that this syntax was best practice in C# up to 5:

```
class Person 
{
    public Person()
    {
        //do anything before variable assignment

        //assign initial values
        Name = "Default Name";

        //do anything after variable assignment
    }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

As this gives you clear control of the order values are assigned.

As of C#6 there is a new way:

```
public string Name { get; set; } = "Default Name";
```

Answer (score 75):

Sometimes I use this, if I don't want it to be actually set and persisted in my db:

```
class Person
{
    private string _name; 
    public string Name 
    { 
        get 
        {
            return string.IsNullOrEmpty(_name) ? "Default Name" : _name;
        } 

        set { _name = value; } 
    }
}
```

Obviously if it's not a string then I might make the object nullable ( double?, int? ) and check if it's null, return a default, or return the value it's set to.

Then I can make a check in my repository to see if it's my default and not persist, or make a backdoor check in to see the true status of the backing value, before saving.

Comment: `return _name ?? "Default Name";` probably even is more clear that your

Comment: @abatishchev: though that is not the same. crucibles code would return "Default Name" if the string is "" or null, but using your approach would return "Default Name" only in case it is null. Also, it is discussible whether "??" or "IsNullOrEmpty" is more clear.

Comment: The point is a default value so a nullable check defeats the point. Keith's answer demonstrates that by initialising it in the Ctor. If it's for the dB I don't really see much difference than having a default column value and make it a non-null column which is going to be more efficient regardless of the number of class fields. I won't down vote but urge Devs to think about this rather than have null / empty checks in your property procedures.

Comment: To clarify everytime you call a class property it will do a null / empty check, where as the dB will only do it on INSERTs or UPDATEs which are typically 20% of the dB work. Instead, potentially every string property has an extra call, it's a waste of cpu cycles and a bad design choice IMHO. Plus there's now Null Ref Type's so dealing with  nullable's is more common.

Answer (score 72):

#### In C# 6.0 this is a breeze!

You can do it in the `Class` declaration itself, in the property declaration statements.

```
public class Coordinate
{ 
    public int X { get; set; } = 34; // get or set auto-property with initializer

    public int Y { get; } = 89;      // read-only auto-property with initializer

    public int Z { get; }            // read-only auto-property with no initializer
                                     // so it has to be initialized from constructor    

    public Coordinate()              // .ctor()
    {
        Z = 42;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't have C#6.0 yet, and was checking to see what version I needed for default values on auto-properties. Does C# 6.0 also remove the need to have `{ get; set; }` or `{ get; private set; }` as otherwise setting the value would be blocked by the compiler?

Answer (score 46):

**Starting with C# 6.0**, We can assign default value to auto-implemented properties.

```
public string Name { get; set; } = "Some Name";
```

We can also create read-only auto implemented property like:

```
public string Name { get; } = "Some Name";
```

See: [C# 6: First reactions , Initializers for automatically implemented properties - By Jon Skeet](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jonskeet/2014/04/04/c-6-first-reactions/)

Answer (score 39):

In Version of *C# (6.0) & greater*, you can do :

**For Readonly properties**

```
public int ReadOnlyProp => 2;
```

**For both Writable & Readable properties**

```
public string PropTest { get; set; } = "test";
```

In current Version of *C# (7.0)*, you can do : (The snippet rather displays how you can use expression bodied get/set accessors to make is more compact when using with backing fields)

```
private string label = "Default Value";

// Expression-bodied get / set accessors.
public string Label
{
   get => label;
   set => this.label = value; 
 }
```

Comment: Also, consider the example `class C { public DateTime P { get; } = DateTime.Now; public DateTime Q => DateTime.Now; }` where both properties `P` and `Q` have a getter only, but the behaviors of `P` and `Q` are very different!

Answer (score 39):

In **C# 9.0** was [added support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/init) of `init` keyword - very useful and **extremly sophisticated way** for declaration *read-only auto-properties*:

Declare:

```
class Person 
{ 
    public string Name { get; init; } = "Anonymous user";
}
```

~Enjoy~ Use:

```
// 1. Person with default name
var anonymous = new Person();
Console.WriteLine($"Hello, {anonymous.Name}!");
// > Hello, Anonymous user!


// 2. Person with assigned value
var me = new Person { Name = "@codez0mb1e"};
Console.WriteLine($"Hello, {me.Name}!");
// > Hello, @codez0mb1e!


// 3. Attempt to re-assignment Name
me.Name = "My fake"; 
// > Compilation error: Init-only property can only be assigned in an object initializer
```

Comment: previously we could just use `public string Name { get; } = "Anonymous user";` the version 9 implementation is more useful for increasing the scope of where you can still set the values. This answer suggests we have to wait for C# 9, which is just untrue for OPs expected behaviour.

Answer (score 23):

In addition to the answer already accepted, for the scenario when you want to define a default property as a *function* of other properties you can use ***expression body notation*** on C#6.0 (and higher) for even more elegant and concise constructs like:

```
public class Person{

    public string FullName  => $"{First} {Last}"; // expression body notation

    public string First { get; set; } = "First";
    public string Last { get; set; } = "Last";
}
```

You can use the above in the following fashion

```
    var p = new Person();

    p.FullName; // First Last

    p.First = "Jon";
    p.Last = "Snow";

    p.FullName; // Jon Snow
```

In order to be able to use the above "=>" notation, the property must be read only, and you do not use the get accessor keyword.

Details on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx)

Comment: `FullName` is a _computed_ property with no backing field, so this doesn't really answer the question, which is about auto properties.

Answer (score 15):

In C# 6 and above you can simply use the syntax:

```
public object Foo { get; set; } = bar;
```

Note that to have a `readonly` property simply omit the set, as so:

```
public object Foo { get; } = bar;
```

You can also assign `readonly` auto-properties from the constructor.

Prior to this I responded as below.

I'd avoid adding a default to the constructor; leave that for dynamic assignments and avoid having two points at which the variable is assigned (i.e. the type default and in the constructor). Typically I'd simply write a normal property in such cases.

One other option is to do what ASP.Net does and define defaults via an attribute:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.defaultvalueattribute.aspx

Comment: Wow, this is a blast from the past. I seem to recall this was based on the reading of the spec (partial excerpt here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645756(v=vs.71).aspx ). Given the time and number of versions (and Roslyn) this could well not the case anymore. Although a counter reference would be appreciated.

Comment: Default assignment happens automatically whether or not you use an initial value or assign in constructor. There is a slight semantic difference - field assignments happen prior to constructor calls - but the null assignment will still happen. See 10.4.5 "all instance fields...are first initialized to their default values, and then the instance field initializers are executed" https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645757(VS.71).aspx

Answer (score 12):

little complete sample:

```
using System.ComponentModel;

private bool bShowGroup ;
[Description("Show the group table"), Category("Sea"),DefaultValue(true)]
public bool ShowGroup
{
    get { return bShowGroup; }
    set { bShowGroup = value; }
}
```

Comment: That won't work. `DefaultValueAttribute` is just a serialization hint, it will not set `ShowGroup` to `true` because the default value for any boolean is `false`.

Comment: This isn't an auto-property.

Answer (score 12):

My solution is to use a custom attribute that provides default value property initialization by constant or using property type initializer.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public class InstanceAttribute : Attribute
{
    public bool IsConstructorCall { get; private set; }
    public object[] Values { get; private set; }
    public InstanceAttribute() : this(true) { }
    public InstanceAttribute(object value) : this(false, value) { }
    public InstanceAttribute(bool isConstructorCall, params object[] values)
    {
        IsConstructorCall = isConstructorCall;
        Values = values ?? new object[0];
    }
}
```

To use this attribute it's necessary to inherit a class from special base class-initializer or use a static helper method:

```
public abstract class DefaultValueInitializer
{
    protected DefaultValueInitializer()
    {
        InitializeDefaultValues(this);
    }

    public static void InitializeDefaultValues(object obj)
    {
        var props = from prop in obj.GetType().GetProperties()
                    let attrs = prop.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(InstanceAttribute), false)
                    where attrs.Any()
                    select new { Property = prop, Attr = ((InstanceAttribute)attrs.First()) };
        foreach (var pair in props)
        {
            object value = !pair.Attr.IsConstructorCall && pair.Attr.Values.Length > 0
                            ? pair.Attr.Values[0]
                            : Activator.CreateInstance(pair.Property.PropertyType, pair.Attr.Values);
            pair.Property.SetValue(obj, value, null);
        }
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
public class Simple : DefaultValueInitializer
{
    [Instance("StringValue")]
    public string StringValue { get; set; }
    [Instance]
    public List<string> Items { get; set; }
    [Instance(true, 3,4)]
    public Point Point { get; set; }
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var obj = new Simple
        {
            Items = {"Item1"}
        };
    Console.WriteLine(obj.Items[0]);
    Console.WriteLine(obj.Point);
    Console.WriteLine(obj.StringValue);
}
```

Output:

```
Item1
(X=3,Y=4)
StringValue
```

Comment: As stated above, using reflection to initialize default values is both slow and overkill. Initialize on the constructor, use a non auto property or on c# 6 and above, use the simplified notation shown in the accepted answer

Comment: When is it better to use this than the other options stated herein?

Answer (score 9):

**You can simple put like this**

```
public sealed  class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; } = 101;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

In the constructor. The constructor's purpose is to initialize its data members.

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried using the [DefaultValueAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.defaultvalueattribute.aspx) or [ShouldSerialize and Reset methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53b8022e%28VS.71%29.aspx) in conjunction with the constructor?  I feel like one of these two methods is necessary if you're making a class that might show up on the designer surface or in a property grid.

Answer (score 6):

```
private string name;
public string Name 
{
    get 
    {
        if(name == null)
        {
            name = "Default Name";
        }
        return name;
    }
    set
    {
        name = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the asker wanted an auto-property, i.e. a non-abstract property in a class or struct where you use just `get;` with a semicolon (often combined with `set;`) to indicate that the compiler should generate the body of the `get` accessor automatically.

Answer (score 4):

Use the constructor because "When the constructor is finished, Construction should be finished". properties are like states your classes hold, if you had to initialize a default state, you would do that in your constructor.

Answer (score 3):

*This is old now, and my position has changed. I'm leaving the original answer for posterity only.*

---

Personally, I don't see the point of making it a property at all if you're not going to do  anything at all beyond the auto-property.  Just leave it as a field.  The encapsulation benefit for these item are just red herrings, because there's nothing behind them to encapsulate.  If you ever need to change the underlying implementation you're still free to refactor them as properties without breaking any dependent code.

Hmm... maybe this will be the subject of it's own question later

Comment: @[Joel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40730/how-do-you-give-a-c-auto-property-a-default-value#41146):  data binding and other reflection-based tools often expect properties rather than fields.

Comment: You cannot refactor a field into an auto property without breaking the calling code. It might look the same same but the generated code is different. With auto properties the calling code calls get_propname and set_propname behind the covers, whereas it just access the field directly if it's a field.

Comment: You cannot access a field across AppDomain boundaries, either -- only a property or method.

Answer (score 3):

To clarify, yes, you need to set default values in the constructor for class derived objects.  You will need to ensure the constructor exists with the proper access modifier for construction where used.  If the object is not instantiated, e.g. it has no constructor (e.g. static methods) then the default value can be set by the field.  The reasoning here is that the object itself will be created only once and you do not instantiate it.

@Darren Kopp - good answer, clean, and correct.  And to reiterate, you CAN write constructors for Abstract methods.  You just need to access them from the base class when writing the constructor:

Constructor at Base Class:

```
public BaseClassAbstract()
{
    this.PropertyName = "Default Name";
}
```

Constructor at Derived / Concrete / Sub-Class:

```
public SubClass() : base() { }
```

The point here is that the instance variable drawn from the base class may bury your base field name.  Setting the current instantiated object value using "this." will allow you to correctly form your object with respect to the current instance and required permission levels (access modifiers) where you are instantiating it.

Answer (score 2):

```
public Class ClassName{
    public int PropName{get;set;}
    public ClassName{
        PropName=0;  //Default Value
    }
}
```

Comment: This is already demonstrated in the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Person 
{    
    /// Gets/sets a value indicating whether auto 
    /// save of review layer is enabled or not
    [System.ComponentModel.DefaultValue(true)] 
    public bool AutoSaveReviewLayer { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Just so you know, bumping up an old question like this is generally frowned upon unless you have some good new information. However, in this case, several others have already posted about the DefaultValue attribute. If someone else has already posted what you were going to say, it's more appropriate to upvote them by clicking on the up arrow above the number next to their answer.

Comment: @fire: Commenting requires 50 reputation.  Voting also requires reputation, IIRC.

Answer (score -1):

I know this is an old question, but it came up when I was looking for how to have a default value that gets inherited with the option to override, I came up with

```
//base class
public class Car
{
    public virtual string FuelUnits
    {
        get { return "gasoline in gallons"; }
        protected set { }
    }
}
//derived
public class Tesla : Car
{
    public override string FuelUnits => "ampere hour";
}
```

Comment: Caution: this does not set an initial value, it creates a get accessor that returns a constant string.   
If the value of FuelUnits is set to another string, FuelUnits will ignore that value and continue to return the literal string defined in the get.

Answer (score -4):

I think this would do it for ya givng SomeFlag a default of false.

```
private bool _SomeFlagSet = false;
public bool SomeFlag
{
    get
    {
        if (!_SomeFlagSet)
            SomeFlag = false;        

        return SomeFlag;
    }
    set
    {
        if (!_SomeFlagSet)
            _SomeFlagSet = true;

        SomeFlag = value;        
    }
}
```