# Why no initial values on {get;set;} accessors (VS 2010 C#)

Tags: c#, properties, default

This must have been asked many times but I cannot find it....sorry...

Why is the following not permitted?

public string MyString = "initial value" {get; private set;}

(Visual C# Express 2010)

Comment: Unfortunate that is isn't possible to do presently - but it wouldn't be damaging to add the ability in future C# versions - I hope they do add it in future. (And add the ability to make readonly auto properties)

Comment: It would be particularly nice if we could flag properties with automatic backing fields to make the backing field `readonly`.  At that point, we could initialize through the property but only in the constructor.  This has been discussed on SO before.

Comment: Finally, a feature where VB allows for a more concise syntax! In VB10, `Public Property MyString As String = "initial value"` works.

Comment: In VS2017 you can do exactly this: MyClass

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you give a C# Auto-Property a default value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40730/how-do-you-give-a-c-sharp-auto-property-a-default-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VS 2017 you can:

```
    public int Minimum { get; private set; } = 0;
    public int Maximum { get; set; } = 5;
```

Answer (score 5):

It's just not valid syntax.  You can't initialize the value of an auto-property, unfortunately.

The best options are to either make the property manually:

```
private string _MyString = "initial value";
public string MyString { get { return _MyString; } set { _MyString = value; } }
```

or initialize the value in the constructor:

```
public string MyString { get; set; }

....

public MyClass() {
    MyString = "initial value";
}
```

Comment: I understand there are various ways. I was just wondering why there wasn't a suitable valid syntax (yet). The problem with the above method is the declaration and initalisation are separated, possibly by many, many lines of code, I like @apollodude217 's  syntax below

Answer (score 2):

An alternative:

```
string _strMyString;

public string MyString
{
    get {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(_strMyString) {
             return "initial value";
        } else { 
             return _strMyString; 
        }
}
```

Comment: I always forget about that method.

Comment: OrEmpty will break your application when you set it to an empty string.

Comment: Very true. It's left up to the programmer to decide whether that behavior is expected or not.

Answer (score 1):

It's a property, not a field.  You can't initialize it this way.  Just set the value in the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

the syntax

```
public string MyString { get; set; }
```

is replacing the old style / annoying / trivial (as of vs2008/c# 3.0 you can see all the new features of c# 3.0 [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/john_charles/WhatnewinVisualStudioNET200802012008121831PM/WhatnewinVisualStudioNET2008.aspx))

```
private string _MyString;

public string MyString 
{
    get { return _MyString; }
    set { _MyString = value; }
}
```

the compiler is actually generates a member  before compiling your code.
you can open a reflector and see the generated member.

Answer (score 1):

> Why?

I cannot speak on behalf of the designers of C#, but I can make educated speculation:

1. They wanted to see just how big of a deal it is before taking the time to
   add another feature and *yet another* rule to the language.
2. They could not find a sufficiently elegant-looking way to do this.

That said, here is how I would allow values (when a set accessor is available, of course):

```
public string MyProp {get;set;} = "initial value"; // not valid C#
```

Without making the language any more complex, they could write the rule so that it applies to "[all] properties with set accessors" instead of to "default properties with set accessors":

```
// again, not valid C#:
public string MyProp
{
    get { return _MyProp;}
    set { _MyProp = value; }
} = "initial value before being massaged or rejected by the set accessor.";
```

The only downside I see here is that it is ugly.  The benefits are that you can concisely specify an initial value for a property with that property instead of in the constructor, and that you can let the value be massaged / checked / whatever via constructor at runtime if you wish.

Comment: Sorry - not enough 'reputation' to edit my own comments after forgetting CR posts the message.