# How do I set a property to a default value in C#?

Tags: c#, properties

so for a user control, I have

```
public int Count { get; set; }
```

so that I can use `this.Count` in another method. The trouble is, I want to set a default for Count to something like `15`. How do I set defaults?

Comment: Can't you just set "Count" to your default value upon initialization?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you give a C# Auto-Property a default value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40730/how-do-you-give-a-c-sharp-auto-property-a-default-value)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the constructor of the userControl

```
public YourUserControl(){
   Count = 15;
}
```

Comment: cool. that will be clean when I have a bunch of defaults in the long run, too.

Answer (score 4):

You will need to set it in the constructor of your class.

For example:

```
public partial class YourControl : UserControl
{
    public int Count { get; set; }

    public YourControl()
    {
         InitializeComponent();

         // Set your default
         this.Count = 15;
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if you use a backing field, you can set it *inline on the field*:

```
public partial class YourControl : UserControl
{
    private int count = 15;
    public int Count 
    {
        get { return this.count; } 
        set { this.count = value; } 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the object that creates your control to set the default, then they can use a property initializer when they new the control.  If you want to set a default for the control, then you would set those defaults in the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You set the default values for automatic properties in the constructor of the class.

```
public MyClass()
{
    Count = 15;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Or alternatively to setting the value in the constructor, which will likely work just fine here, use the *long* approach.

```
int _count = 15;
public int Count {
  get { return _count; }
  set { _count = value; }
}
```

Sometimes this way is useful if the appropriate constructor is *not called* for some reason (such as some Serialization/Activation techniques).

Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using an auto implemented property you can write your own property based on an underlying field containing your default value:

```
private int _count = 15;
public int Count
{
    get { return _count; }
    set { _count = value; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the DefaultValueAttribute. More info here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.defaultvalueattribute.aspx

This question is a possible duplicate: [How do you give a C# Auto-Property a default value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40730/how-do-you-give-a-c-auto-property-a-default-value)

Comment: This doesn't set the default value :( I thought it did at one time and found out the hard way I was incorrect. Rather, it is used to allow serialization techniques (and such) to *not serialize* the default value and thus save space (e.g. `[DataMember(EmitDefault=false)]`). It is also used in designers for the "reset" value, etc.

Comment: @pst: You are right, I just saw the fine print... This is also helpful for the Visual Designer in Visual Studio.