# Entity Framework - Default value for property using Data Annotations

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, data-annotations

I have a model like this

```
public class MyModel
{
    public int MyModelId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

I was wondering if there's a way, using Data Annotations, to set the value of a property - say Title - default to other property value, i.e. Name. Something like:

```
if(MyModel.Title == "") MyModel.Title = MyModel.Name;
```

Comment: Possible Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40730/how-do-you-give-a-c-auto-property-a-default-value

Comment: I'm trying to achieve this with Data Annotations, though I don't think it's possible. Anyway I don't think it is a dupe.

Comment: it's not quite the same, but if you read the answers and comments you'll see that they answer your question

Comment: Yes but the answers are from 2008. EF went 4.1 this year. Something could be new.

Comment: Doesn't appear so http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg197525(VS.103).aspx

Answer (score 10):

If you want default value set it in entity default (parameterless) constructor. There is no need to have data annotation for something which you can do directly.

Comment: Default values are useful when adding a non-nullable column to an existing table with records in it.  I was searching for a way to do it and came across this question - is there a way to specify the value to populate for all existing records?

Comment: @Crake this should probably be its own separate question, but I was able to do this with `defaultValueSql` in my data migration: `AddColumn("ExistingTable", "NewColumn",c => c.Int(nullable: false, defaultValueSql: "0"));` (change type and default value as necessary)

Answer (score 4):

you can tell entity framework that database will take care of that property by editing that property in SSDL of the edmx file.

**Initially**

`<Property Name="CompanyName" Type="nvarchar" Nullable="false" MaxLength="40"  />`

**we have change it to**

`<Property Name="CompanyName" Type="nvarchar" Nullable="false" MaxLength="40" StoreGeneratedPattern="Computed" />`

by setting  storeGeneratedPattern="Computed" we can tell to EF that the property value will be inserted by DB.

For Editing SSDL

1. Right click the edmx file, open with XML(text) Editor.

2.Ctrl+F name of the property  and just change that property

I don't know is there a way to do with data annotations.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to set attribute argument as a function in general, you will get an error:

"An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type"