# LINQ to entity - Triggers and Table Defaults

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

I have a database table called Room.

This table has some defaults on certain columns:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Room] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Room_Created]  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [Created]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Room] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Room_Updated]  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [Updated]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Room] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Room_RecordStatus]  DEFAULT (0) FOR [RecordStatus]
```

The table also has the following trigger:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[RoomInsert] ON [dbo].[Room]
FOR INSERT 
AS
DECLARE @PKey int, @TrackingId int
SELECT @PKey = PKey, @TrackingId = TrackingId FROM INSERTED
IF @TrackingId = 0
UPDATE Room
SET TrackingId = @PKey
WHERE PKey = @PKey
```

We are currently developing an MVC 3 Web application which uses Entity Framework 4. When I run the following code none of the defaults are applied and the trigger is not fired:

```
// Create the new room record
                Room newRoom = new Room();
                newRoom.SiteKey = parentFloor.SiteKey;
                newRoom.SiteSurveyKey = parentFloor.SiteSurveyKey;
                newRoom.BuildingKey = parentFloor.BuildingKey;
                newRoom.FloorKey = parentFloor.PKey;
                newRoom.Name = eventModel.RoomName;
                newRoom.Description = eventModel.RoomName;
                newRoom.CreatedBy = eventModel.UserKey;

                _entities.Rooms.AddObject(newRoom);
                _entities.SaveChanges();
```

I have ran a profile on the database and the insert produces the following:

```
exec sp_executesql N'insert [dbo].[Room]([TrackingID], [OriginalPKey], [BuildingKey], [SiteSurveyKey], [SiteKey], [Name], [Description], [RiskColour], [CreatedBy], [Created], [Updated], [RecordStatus], [FloorKey], [DisplayOrder])
values (null, null, @0, @1, @2, @3, @4, null, @5, null, null, null, @6, null)
select [PKey]
from [dbo].[Room]
where @@ROWCOUNT > 0 and [PKey] = scope_identity()',N'@0 int,@1 int,@2 int,@3 varchar(255),@4 varchar(255),@5 int,@6 int',@0=29970,@1=20177,@2=39373,@3='Another Room ',@4='Another Room ',@5=139,@6=25454
```

I am guessing that the defaults are not applied because NULL is specifically passed and the trigger is not fired because of sp_executesql. Is there any way to get around this?

Comment: One comment: your trigger is coded to only work when inserted has only one row in it. In cases where you bulk insert, it will fail. You should always code triggers to assume that bulk operations may take place (even it you're using EF).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @JustAnother... says, the contraints will be of little use, as you'll always have a value supplied, however your trigger should still work ok.

In the SQL trace you'll see that the value of `TrackingID` is null. In your trigger you're testing for `TrackingID=0`, which is false when `TrackingID = null`.

Try updating the trigger to test for `null` as well.

Comment: Yes you are right. Thanks, before the trigger was relying on the TrackingID having a default of 0, which as I now know won't happen in EF so I have changed the trigger to IF ISNULL(@TrackingId, 0) = 0 which seems to do the trick

Answer (score 1):

Entity Framework does not care about your default constraints. It will always submit a value, as long as your column is not marked as Identity or Computed in your EF model. When you change the column to "Computed", you can't update the column with your entity object anymore, it will always take the database value (and therefor your default-constraint value).

Answer (score 1):

When you use EF you basically just have to accept that the application is the master, not the database.

You should set default values in your `Room` constructor, not through database default constraints (admittedly with created / updated date you might want to do this at the db for timezone reasons etc...)

[Entity Framework - Default value for property using Data Annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6273303/entity-framework-default-value-for-property-using-data-annotations)