# C# Auto-Implemented Properties

Tags: c#, .net

I am fairly new to auto-implemented properties and for the most of it I find them pretty straight forward but in the Microsoft site it states:

> In C# 3.0 and later, auto-implemented properties make property-declaration more concise when no additional logic is required in the property accessors. **They also enable client code to create objects.** When you declare a property as shown in the following example, the compiler creates a private, anonymous backing field that can only be accessed through the property's get and set accessors.
>
> -- [Auto-Implemented Properties (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx)

Can anyone explain what the following statement actually means with regard to auto-implemented properties:  "**They also enable client code to create objects.**"?

I cannot figure out what this means.

Thanks.

Comment: similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40730/how-do-you-give-a-c-auto-property-a-default-value

Comment: The real benefit of auto properties: DataBinding (which of course does not work on fields without a custom `TypeDescriptor`).

Comment: The answer is, that's just a crappy bit of explanation from MSDN, I feel

Comment: One of many bad explanations in MSDN unfortunately.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe this refers to [object initializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx) syntax, though why this would be the case is not clear. Auto implemented properties and object initializers are separate things and shouldn't be linked together this way.

So, with a class that looks like this:

```
public class Cat
{
    // Auto-implemented properties.
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

You can create objects like this:

```
Cat cat = new Cat { Age = 10, Name = "Fluffy" };
```

Note:

As the comments say (and the MSDN page on object initializers declares), you can use object initializer syntax with *any* accessible field or property. Again, the fact that the MSDN page on auto-implemented properties even mentions object creation appears to be a bad documentation decision.

Comment: You can do the same with public fields.

Comment: And regular properties too. Basically, anything that can be set with a `Foo.x = y;` line.

Comment: @leppie - true. From MSDN: `Object initializers let you assign values to any accessible fields or properties`.

Comment: And with normal Properties (private field, public setters)... So while the statment is true it is also true for non-automatic properties.

Comment: @Oded: Not me, but I am partially offended by `private class`  ;P

Comment: @Oded: Downvote removed after your edit, while i believe as you and jon that they refer to initializer syntax they are incorrect and the answer was letting the OP believe that there really was a link between them (other that they are useful together to minimize code both during the declaration of a class and the creation of a new instance)

Comment: Thanks for all the replies. I thought I was missing something but the general consensus seems to be that it is simply bad documentation. I was aware of the object initializer syntax but I wasn't sure if this is what they were referring to. Cheers.

Answer (score 4):

That's a bad description on the MSDN page, unfortunately.

Object initializer syntax (`new Foo { X = 10, Y = 20 }`) is *completely separable* from automatically implemented properties.

Object initializers can be used with *any* settable properties or fields (and there's even syntax for mutating "subproperties" when the "main property" is read-only); you don't have to use an automatically implemented property for this.

While it's nice that all these features work together, I believe it's useful to at least *learn* about them separately. For example, automatically implemented properties could have been introduced in C# 2 without object initializers - or vice versa.

Comment: Didn't know about initialising properties of read-only properties. That's pretty nifty.

Comment: @Anton: I've mostly seen it for initializing collections: Foo f = new Foo { SomeCollection = { new Item(), new Item() };`. Here the `SomeCollection` property is read-only, but returns a `List<Item>` which can be added to.

Comment: True, I s'pose it's similar - but collections are special-cased, aren't they? (either `ICollection` or anything which has a public `Add`, I forget which :P) **EDIT** Make that `IEnumerable` *and* a public `Add`.

Comment: @Anton: Yup, IEnumerable and Add it is. My point is that it's the same syntax: `= { ... }` as opposed to `= value`.

Answer (score 1):

I think what they mean by

> "They also enable client code to create objects."

is that the client code can init a new ref type object or assign a value type object to the auto property without having to create a private field to hold onto the data.

Oded has the example for the value type, so lets expand upon his Cat class

```
private class Cat
{
    // Auto-implemented properties.
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<Cat> Kittens { get; set; }
}

Cat cat = new Cat { Age = 10, Name = "Fluffy" }; //borrowed fluffy for this example
cat.Kittens = new List<Cat>();

cat.Kittens.Add( new Cat() { Age = 0, Name = "Pinky" } );
cat.Kittens.Add( new Cat() { Age = 0, Name = "Blinky" } );
```

Comment: Again, there's nothing unique to auto-properties here. I think Jon Skeet's on the money here: It's just a very poorly worded document.

Answer (score -1):

You can Add logic to getter function by accessing values of another property there by auto implementing property values

```
 public string Status
    {
        get { return DeactivateDate != null ? "InActive" : "Active"; }
        private set { }
    }
```