# Access multiple methods stored in an Action[] dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary, console-application, morse-code

[This question covers the use of actions in a dictionary.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7173747/using-action-dictionaries-instead-of-switch-statements) I want to do something similar, but with **more than one method** per action:

```
static readonly Dictionary<char, Action[]> morseDictionary = new Dictionary<char,Action[]>
        {
            { 'a', new Action[] {dot, dash} },
            { 'b', new Action[] {dash, dot, dot, dot} },
            { 'c', new Action[] {dash, dot, dash, dot} },
            { 'd', new Action[] {dash, dot, dot} },
            { 'e', new Action[] {dot} }
            // etc
        };
```

`dot` and `dash` refer to these private functions:

```
private static void dash(){
    Console.Beep(300, timeUnit*3);
}

private static void dot(){
    Console.Beep(300, timeUnit);
}
```

I have another function, `morseThis`, which is designed to convert a message string to audio output:

```
private static void morseThis(string message){
    char[] messageComponents = message.ToCharArray();
    if (morseDictionary.ContainsKey(messageComponents[i])){
        Action[] currentMorseArray = morseDictionary[messageComponents[i]];
        Console.WriteLine(currentMorseArray); // prints "System.Action[]"
    }       
}
```

In the example above, I am able to print "System.Action[]" to the console for every letter contained in the input message. However, my intention is to call the methods within `currentMorseArray` in order.

**How do I access the methods contained within a given Action[] in my dictionary?**

Comment: For your specific case I would just store a lamda as the (single) action. So `... { 'a', () => { dot(); dash(); }, ...`. That keeps the invocation simple and doesn't really change the dictionary setup all that much. You might also consider making the field's type IReadOnlyDictionary, given that I don't think its contents are intended to be changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're nearly there. You've got an array of actions, so now all you need to do is execute the actions in order.

`Action`s and `Func`s in C# are just like any other object - you can put them in arrays, assign them to variables, pass them to methods as arguments, and so on. The only difference is that you can *call* an action. The syntax for this looks just like the syntax for calling a method:

```
Action myAction = ...
myAction();  // call the action
```

So to execute the actions in your array, you can just `foreach` down the array to pull them out one by one, and call each one in the body of the loop.

```
private static void morseThis(string message)
{
    char[] messageComponents = message.ToCharArray();

    if (morseDictionary.ContainsKey(messageComponents[i]))
    {
        Action[] currentMorseArray = morseDictionary[messageComponents[i]];

        foreach (Action action in currentMorseArray)
        {
            action();
        }
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Enumerate the actions and execute them.

```
private static void morseThis(string message)
{
    char[] messageComponents = message.ToCharArray();

    foreach(char c in messageComponents)
    {
        Action[] actions;

        if (morseDictionary.TryGetValue(c, out actions))
        {
            foreach(Action action in actions)
            {
              action();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `foreach` to iterate over array of actions:

```
private static void morseThis(string message){
    char[] messageComponents = message.ToCharArray();
    Action[] currentMorseArray;
    if (morseDictionary.TryGetValue(messageComponents[i], out currentMorseArray))
    {
        foreach(var action in currentMorseArray)
        {
            action();
        }
    }       
}
```

I'm not sure what  you *expected* from `Console.WriteLine`, but behavior you observe is expected as `WriteLine` calls `ToString` on the object to print it and for arrays (and other types where `ToString` is not overridden) it simply returns type name.

Answer (score 0):

```
static readonly Dictionary<char, List<Action>> morseDictionary = new Dictionary<char,List<Action>>
        {
            { 'a', new List<Action> {dot, dash} },
            { 'b', new List<Action> {dash, dot, dot, dot} },
            { 'c', new List<Action> {dash, dot, dash, dot} },
            { 'd', new List<Action> {dash, dot, dot} },
            { 'e', new List<Action> {dot} }
            // etc
        };

private static void morseThis(string messageSrc)
{
    foreach(char message in messageSrc.ToCharArray())
    {
        List<Action> currentMorseArray;
        if (morseDictionary.TryGetValue(message, out currentMorseArray))
        {
            currentMorseArray.ForEach(x=>x());
        }   
    }    
}
```