# How can I initialize a default value in C#?

Tags: c#

I want to have a default value for a boolean `crossover` of `false`
How can I initialize it?

```
public class DecisionBar
{
public DateTime bartime 
     { get; set; }
public string frequency
         { get; set; }
public bool HH7
        {get;set;}
public bool crossover
        {get;set;}
public double mfe
        {get;set;}
    public double mae
        {get;set;}
public double entryPointLong
        {get;set;}
public double entryPointShort
        {get;set;}


}
```

Comment: depends on what you are trying to achieve. You could put it in the constructor and initialise that way. But the object will always have to be instantiated for the value to be set. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Try read about constructors. public DecisionBar() { crossover = false; }

Comment: Please have a look : **http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ace5hbzh%28v=vs.71%29.aspx**

Comment: may be duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40730/how-do-you-give-a-c-sharp-auto-property-a-default-value

Comment: The default value of `crossover` is already `false`

Comment: Is it important to software design, that a bool have false on instantiation? I would set its default explicitly in a constructor, as a clarification to anyone who may see the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apart from the fact that the default value is false, there are two options. Obviously they are redundant, but if you wanted the default value to true you could use either method.

Either don't use an auto-implemented property, instead using a backing property;

```
private bool _crossover = false;

public bool crossover 
{
 get { return _crossover; }
 set { _crossover = value; }
}
```

or in the constructor;

```
public DecisionBar() 
{
 crossover = false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The default value of any `bool` is `false` so you really don't need to do anything in this case.

If, however, you wanted `true` to be the default value, you could have an explicit backing private field of `crossover` and initialize that to be `true`:

```
private bool _co = true;
public bool crossover
{
   get { return _co; }
   set { _co = value; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The default value of a boolean is `false`. I'm not sure what you mean here.

If you want to set it explicitly. Put this in the class.

```
private bool _crossover = false;

public bool crossover 
{
    get
    {
        return _crossover;
    }
    set
    {
        _crossover = value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private bool _crossover = false;//or true
public bool Crossover {get {return _crossover;}set{_crossover =value;}}
```

Answer (score 0):

**from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c8f5xwh7%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):**

[The default value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83fhsxwc.aspx) of the [`bool`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c8f5xwh7.aspx) is `false`; The default value of a `bool?` variable is `null`. Default constructors are invoked by using the new operator, as follows:

```
var decisionBar = new DecisionBar();
var myBool = decisionBar.crossover; // 'myBool' should be 'false'
```

The preceding statement has the same effect as the following statement:

```
var decisionBar = new DecisionBar();
decisionBar.crossover = false;
```

See this post:
[How do you give a C# Auto-Property a default value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40730/how-do-you-give-a-c-sharp-auto-property-a-default-value)