# How can I make my Linq select return values if the value selected is null?

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following code:

```
    [DisplayName("Created")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
    public DateTime? Created { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Modified By")]
    public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Modified")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
    public DateTime? Modified { get; set; }

        from d in data
        select new Content.Grid
        {
            PartitionKey = d.PartitionKey,
            RowKey = d.RowKey,
            Order = d.Order,
            Title = d.Title,e
            Created = d.Created,
            CreatedBy = d.CreatedBy,
            Modified = d.Modified,
            ModifiedBy = d.ModifiedBy
        };
```

There is a possibility that `d.Created`, `d.CreatedBy`, `d.Modified` and `d.ModifiedBy` may be null.

How can I make it so that if they are null then the select returns `n/a` for the `CreatedBy` and `ModifiedBy` and returns the date `January, 1, 2012` for the `Created` and `Modified`?

Comment: This isnt really anything to do with Linq. new Content.Grid { ... } is an Object Initializer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the [null-coalescing operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) (`??`) to give default values for nullable value types or reference types:

```
from d in data
select new Content.Grid
{
    PartitionKey = d.PartitionKey,
    RowKey = d.RowKey,
    Order = d.Order,
    Title = d.Title,e
    Created = d.Created ?? new DateTime(2012,1,1),
    CreatedBy = d.CreatedBy ?? "n/a",
    Modified = d.Modified ?? new DateTime(2012,1,1),
    ModifiedBy = d.ModifiedBy ?? "n/a"
};
```

Comment: This looks very good. I have another select with a join where I use: Type = t == null ? null : t.Value,   Could I also use this operator for that?

Comment: No this is a different construct.  null-coalescing is for the case when you have `null` but you want something else than `null`. In your join if you have `null` you still want `null` otherwise you want something else. So only cases like this: `Type = t == null ? SomeDefaultType : t` can be reformulated to `Type = t ?? SomeDefaultType`

Comment: Thanks this works , initially i tried to use constructor in my class to set default values to properties using [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43594/2218697) example , but it didn't work why ?

Comment: How do you assign a boolean value of false if d.boolfield == true?