# How do I manipulate an object's properties after it has been added to a List in C#

Tags: c#, list, class, object, properties

Say I have a class like this:

```
class public Person
{
    public string firstName;
    public string lastName;
    public string address;
    public string city;
    public string state;
    public string zip;

    public Person(string firstName, string lastName)
    {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

And let's further say I create a List of type Person like this:

```
List<Person> pList = new List<Person>;
pList.Add(new Person("Joe", "Smith");
```

Now, I want to set the address, city, state, and zip for Joe Smith, but I have already added the object to the list.  So, how do I set these member variables, *after* the object has been added to the list?

Thank you.

Comment: You really shouldn't be exposing the fields publicly; it would be more appropriate to use properties.  Thanks to auto implemented properties it's very little additional effort.

Comment: I appreciate the advice. Can you please elaborate further with an example?

Comment: Google is there for a reason.  Use it.

Comment: @user717236 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40730/how-do-you-give-a-c-sharp-auto-property-a-default-value

Comment: @user717236: I edited my answer to show a bit the use of such automatic properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the first item of the list like so:

`Person p = pList[0];` or `Person p = pList.First();`

Then you can modify it as you wish:

`p.firstName = "Jesse";`

Also, I would recommend using automatic properties:

```
class public Person
{
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    public string lastName { get; set; }
    public string address { get; set; }
    public string city { get; set; }
    public string state { get; set; }
    public string zip { get; set; }

    public Person(string firstName, string lastName)
    {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

You'll get the same result, but the day that you'll want to verify the input or change the way that you set items, it will be much simpler:

```
class public Person
{
    private const int ZIP_CODE_LENGTH = 6;
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    public string lastName { get; set; }
    public string address { get; set; }
    public string city { get; set; }
    public string state { get; set; }
    private string zip_ = null;
    public string zip 
    { 
        get { return zip_; } 
        set
        {
            if (value.Length != ZIP_CODE_LENGTH ) throw new Exception("Invalid zip code.");
            zip_ = value;
        }
    }

    public Person(string firstName, string lastName)
    {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

Quite possibly not the best decision to just crash when you set a property here, but you get the general idea of being able to quickly change how an object is set, without having to call a `SetZipCode(...);` function everywhere. Here is all the magic of encapsulation an OOP.

Answer (score 4):

You get the item back out of the list and then set it:

```
pList[0].address = "123 Main St.";
```

Answer (score 3):

You can keep a reference to your object around. Try adding like this:

```
List<Person> pList = new List<Person>;
Person p = new Person("Joe", "Smith");
pList.Add(p);
p.address = "Test";
```

Alternatively you can access it directly through the list.

```
pList[0].address = "Test";
```

Comment: Well, no, actually, you don't need to keep a reference around.  You *can*, but you don't *need* to.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the item through it's index. If you want to find the *last* item added then you can use the length - 1 of your list:

```
List<Person> pList = new List<Person>;
// add a bunch of other items....
// ....
pList.Add(new Person("Joe", "Smith");
pList[pList.Length - 1].address = "....";
```

Answer (score 1):

Should you have lost track of the element you're looking for in your list, you can always use LINQ to find the element again:

```
pList.First(person=>person.firstName == "John").lastName = "Doe";
```

Or if you need to relocate all "Doe"s at once, you can do:

```
foreach (Person person in pList.Where(p=>p.lastName == "Doe"))
{
    person.address = "Niflheim";
}
```