# Return the [DefaultValue] if property is not initialized in c#

Tags: c#, properties, default-value, custom-attributes

I'm wondering what is the cleanest way to make a property return the value specified in its [DefaultValueAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.defaultvalueattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) if not initialized.

For example, I would like the getter of this property to return 42 if not initialized:

```
[DefaultValue(42)]
public int MyProperty { get; set; }
```

Any solution / refactored code welcomed. Target is .Net 4 (if greater, please indicate a fallback)

Ultimately, the aim is to avoid "hardcoding" the default value twice in order to facilitate maintenance. Also note that in a real scenario, there would be several such properties in one class. So ideally, I would prefer to avoid a solution that manually lists and initializes each properties to its default value.

Comment: Possible solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6444527/1010492

Comment: I can only see one solution there that uses the DefaultValueAttribute (uses TypeDescriptor to initialize the properties that have a default value in the constructor). Any other solution? Any way to work on the property getters instead?

Comment: Can do `System.ComponentModel.DefaultValue(42)`