# How to Construct C# Class with Many Default Paramters and Have Ability to Override Them

Tags: c#, .net, class, default-constructor

I am writing a class with member variables. I want to define default values for these fields and have to ability to override them with custom set values. I want to create some sort of class or struct in order to hold the data for these variables. I want someone using the class to have the ability to define all of the variables, or if they don't then the fields will be set to defaults (which I would define). Not sure of cleanest way to do this. This is what I have in mind but I'm not sure if I can do better:

```
public class ReportPageParams 
{
    public float Width { get; private set; }
    public float Height { get; private set; }
    public float LeftMargin { get; private set; }
    public float RightMargin { get; private set; }
    public float TopMargin { get; private set; }
    public float BottomMargin { get; private set; }

    //Constructor
    ReportPageParams(float pWidth, pHeight) 
    {
        Width = 52f
        Height = 52f
        //...
    }
}

public class ReportPage  
{
    //same fields as ReportPageParams plus some more
    private float _width, _height;
    private float _leftMargin;
    private float _rightMargin;
    //...

    ReportPage(ReportPageParams pCustomParams = null) 
    {
        if (pCustomParams != null) 
        {
            _width = pCustomParams.Width
            _height = pCustomParams.Height
            //...
        }
        else
        {
            //set fields to default values
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What version of C# are you using, Are you making your code in Visual studio 2015? If you are there are more options available to you.

Comment: `public float Width { get; private set; } = 1.222 or something` will set default value for property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick and dirty way: make your properties `protected set`, then create a class that is derived from your defaults. Only your base and derived classes will be able to make changes due to the properties being `protected`.

```
public class ReportPageParams
{
    public float Width { get; protected set; }
    public float Height { get; protected set; }
    public float LeftMargin { get; protected set; }
    public float RightMargin { get; protected set; }
    public float TopMargin { get; protected set; }
    public float BottomMargin { get; protected set; }

    //Constructor
    public ReportPageParams(float pWidth, float pHeight) 
    {
        Width = 52f
        Height = 52f
        //...
    }
}

public class ReportPageParamsWithLargeLeftMargin : ReportPageParams
{
    //Constructor
    public ReportPageParamsWithLargeLeftMargin(float pWidth, float pHeight)
        : base(pWidth, pHeight)
    {
        LeftMargin = 100;
    }
}
```

You'll find whatever values you set in the constructor for `ReportPageParams` will also appear in `ReportPageParamsWithLargeLeftMargin`. Because constructors are executed in order from the class closest to `object` to more specific classes, your changed defaults will be applied.

Alternatively, you can make the properties `virtual` and derive a class that overrides them with `override`. This puts you in charge of handling the property yourself.

Comment: Hey thanks for the solution. I like this. If I could I would combine this with jdphenix's solution, but I'm not using C# 6 so I guess I'll just stick to a default constructor.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using C# 6, you can use [default values for auto implemented properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40730/how-do-you-give-a-c-sharp-auto-property-a-default-value):

```
public sealed class ImAComplex
{
    public float TypeWith { get; private set; } = 20.0f;
    public float LotsOf { get; private set; } = 40.0f;
    public float PropertiesWith { get; private set; } = 20.0f;
    public float DefaultValues { get; private set; } = 10.0f;
    public float ThatGoOn { get; private set; } = 40.0f;
    public float AndOn { get; private set; } = 20.0f;
    public float ForALong { get; private set; } = 90.0f;
    public float TimeBefore { get; private set; } = 12.5f;
    public float FinallyEnding { get; private set; } = 80.0f;

    // ... 
}
```

If before that, there's still options to keep your public facing interface clean. You just have to do it the old fashioned way -

```
private float typeWith = 20.0f;
public float TypeWith
{
    get
    {
        return typeWith; 
    }
    private set
    {
        typeWith = value;
    }
}
// repeat ad nauseum
```

One technique I like is using static factory methods, which I like because you can name them based upon their function ("what kind of `ImaComplex` does I return" rather than "I return an `ImAComplex`"), for example:

```
    public static ImAComplex WithBigTimeBefore(float typeWith, float lotsOf)
    {
        return new ImAComplex
        {
            TypeWith = typeWith,
            LotsOf = lotsOf, 
            TimeBefore = BigValue 
        };
    }
```

If you use static factory methods, be sure to make the constructor private. It's as simple as `private ImAComplex() { }` to keep outside code from instantiating it.