# Give a start value to a get/set variable

Tags: get, set

Is it possible to give a start value to a variable that has a get and setter? So it should look something like this:

```
public static float myVariable = 10 {get; set;};
```

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**

Working in C#

**Edit 2:**

So I tried this:

```
public static class GlobalVariables {

    public static float groundSearchRayDistance{get;}

        static GlobalVariables()
    {
        groundSearchRayDistance = 10;
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40730/how-do-you-give-a-c-sharp-auto-property-a-default-value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 public class ClassName{
     public ClassName(){
        myVariable = 10;
    }
    public static float myVariable {get; set;} 
 }
```

Comment: Unexpected symbol `=' in class, struct, or interface member declaration

Answer (score 0):

Dunno what language you are using, but usually you would put that within the constructor. You would just override the constructor of that variable to take a number and make that the initial value. Hope that helps! if not, give details!

Comment: I am using c# and aaah ofcourse I can use a constructor in a static class as well. Did not think about that. Thanks.

Comment: Yea, I'm not hugely experienced in c#, but I'd think that would work. If it does, please mark question as answered :)

Comment: It didn't work :O. I added the thing I tried to my origional question.

Comment: Like I've said, it's been ages since I've done a c-like language, but you may need that to be this.groundSearchRayDistance = 10; so that you are changing it in the actual object instance, not the class.