# Can I set a property in a c# class to always have a specific default value?

Tags: c#, properties

I have a C# class with properties in which I end up using this class a a collection of type List in another class.

What I want to do is just always set the Type property to be of value "3"

Should /Can this be done with the  getter/setter or should I use the System.Component.DefaultValue .... attribute

```
public class ReportDefinition 
{

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ReportGroupNameDef { get; set; }
    public int SortOrder { get; set; }
    public int ReportGroupId { get; set; }

    [System.ComponentModel.DefaultValue(3)]
    public int Type { get; set; }

}
```

I think that I would prefer not using this way `[System.ComponentModel.DefaultValue(3)]`

Comment: If [c# 6 or higher](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40730/how-do-you-give-a-c-sharp-auto-property-a-default-value): `public int Type { get; set; } = 3;`

Comment: c# 6 is .net 4.5 ?

Comment: well, my Linqpad complains about it...  Linqpad 4  ....  what other way ?

Comment: I do like to do POC in linqpad,  but I do end up putting code into VS 2015

Comment: LinqPad 5 supports it, and no, C# 6 is a roslyn compilation feature. Language version is not dependent on .net version.

Comment: Right, i hear you  - While I'm using VS 2015 90% of the time,  still have too many other applications with developers on VS 2013 , and I have not bought the Linqpad 5.... sure free version is there but limited...  I bought linqpad 4 years ago...     I seem to spend 50% of my time on the frontend with javascript and all sorts of frameworks... so I guess for me to really dig into all the C# 6 new features simply has not been on my priority list of things to currently learn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a read-only property, and either return the value of a private field, or just return the value you want right in the `get`.

```
public class ReportDefinition
{
  private int m_type = 3;
  public int Type 
  { 
    get 
    {
      return m_type; 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You could also consider using an enum instead of a [Magic Number](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/GemingLeader/refactoring-magic-numbers/) if that is what `3` represents.

Comment: What is wrong with this answer that someone downvoted it.   I really think people should be required to leave a comment on any downvote, even if you wish to be set as anonymous

Comment: This works as I have 3 classes of which the main class I need to know that it is the main thus it will get Type = 1 , then another class with properties having Type set to 2 ,  another to Type of 3  ,   I'm representing database tables that don't have obvious ways to know when the data is sent out to kendo / javascript , then a ajax call is made with the data and its children items,  i need to know which set of data and children belong to a specific table .   I explain all that here as I fail the pain of Zach being downvoted.   I have not yet committed myself to C# 6 , so thus this seems good.

Answer (score 0):

I don't expect to get or steal away the existing selected answer but I did want to help clarify a bit of the comments that I am reading.

1. Yes indeed best clean way is auto-property    `public int Type { get; } = 3;`   -- **Caveat is C# 6**
2. Another C# 6 without auto-property would be an **expression body**

   ```
   private int m_type = 3;
   public int Type => m_type;
   ```
3. However If you are stuck with wanting to use Linqpad 4 then the selected answer is "fine"

   ```
   private int m_type = 3;
   public int Type 
   { 
     get 
     {
         return m_type; 
     }
   }
   ```