# How do you give a C# Auto-Property a default value When the Property is a Class

Tags: c#

there is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40730/how-do-you-give-a-c-sharp-auto-property-a-default-value). However my property is not an `int` or a `string` but a `class` itself with many properties of its own. So i want to set the default value to a property of a property.

So here is my example:

```
public class Claim
{
    public Person Member { get; set; }
    public Person Claimant { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see my properties arent `int`'s or `string`'s put they are `Person`'s. Each person has many properties and I want to set the default value of one of them for each object.

For example if I make a new person Like this:

```
Person Pete = new Person { PersonTypeID = 1 };
```

As you can see `Person` has a `PersonTypeID` property. Lets say I want to set that value as `1` for `Member` and `2` for `Claimant` as default values every time the `Claim` class in instantiated. How can I do this?

Comment: when you initialize `Claim`, the properties are auto assigned to their default values by the compiler.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since C#6 you can initialize [auto-implemented properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx):

```
public Person Member { get; set; } = new Person { PersonTypeID = 1 }; // or by using the constructor of Person
public Person Claimant { get; set; } = new Person { PersonTypeID = 2 };
```

otherwise use the constructor of `Claim`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in a lazy way

```
public class Claim
{
    public Person Member { get; set; }
    public Person Claimant { get; set; }

    public Claim()
    {
        this.Member = new Person() { PersonTypeID = 1 };
        this.Claimant = new Person() { PersonTypeID = 2 };
    }
}
```

or

```
public class Claim
{
    public Person Member { get; set; }
    public Person Claimant { get; set; }

    public Claim(int MemberTypeID, int ClaimantTypeID)
    {
        this.Member = new Person() { PersonTypeID = MemberTypeID };
        this.Claimant = new Person() { PersonTypeID = ClaimantTypeID };
    }
}
```

Comment: or the IoC-way: inject `Person` instance in the ctor, or provide a factory-method, or ...