# Auto-property initialization

Tags: c#

Let's assume, we have following class:

```
public class foo 
{
    private string something
    public string Something
    {
        get { return something; }
        set { something = value; }
    }
}
```

If we don't need to use field something, we can write it shortly, as:

```
public class foo
{
    public string Something { get; set; }
}
```

It's OK.

But is there a way to short-write following class:?

```
public class foo 
{
    private List<string> something = new List<string>()
    public List<string> Something
    {
        get { return something; }
        set { something = value; }
    }
}
```

EDIT:

OK, found 
[How do you give a C# Auto-Property a default value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40730/how-do-you-give-a-c-sharp-auto-property-a-default-value)

And since c# 6 we can write:

```
public List<string> Something { get; set; } = new List<string>();
```

Thanks for attention.

Comment: there is a DefaultValueAttribute. But im afraid it will not work for reference types...

Comment: Dupicate of
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40730/how-do-you-give-a-c-sharp-auto-property-a-default-value

Comment: @Mat the `[DefaultValueAttribute]` doesn't _assign_ a value to a property, it just notifies editors and such what value you will be applying to it by default.

Comment: @C.Evenhuis Thx for the clarification. Didn't knew that ;-)