# Default value set for auto property is not working

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I have created a property like below and the default value specified is not working.

```
[DefaultValue(100)]
public int MyProperty
{
   get;
   set;
}
```

but the property doesn't returns the specified default value, instead it returns 'O'

Could anyone please clarify me?

Regards,

Comment: Follow this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40730/how-do-you-give-a-c-sharp-auto-property-a-default-value

Answer (score 2):

If you're using c# 6.0 you can use this to set default property value:

```
public int MyProperty { get; set; } = 100;
```

Comment: There is no need to post a duplicate of my answer

Comment: When I posted, your answer had only info about DefaultValue attribute.

Answer (score 1):

You're using a `DefaultValue` attribute.

> A DefaultValueAttribute will not cause a member to be automatically initialized with the attribute's value. You must set the initial value in your code.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.defaultvalueattribute(v=vs.110).aspx

In C# 5 an below, to give properties a default value, you have to do it in the constructor.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass() {
        MyProperty = 100;
    }

    public int MyProperty {get; set;}
}
```

In version 6 (and above) of C# you can do:

```
public int MyProperty { get; set; } = 100;
```