# Is setting variables null in a model a good way to make the variable null (until it's changed)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Ints/doubles in my app convert themselves to "0" if no value is entered by the user in the view. To stop this from happening I use "= null" in my model.

Eg.

```
public double? Distance { get; set; } = null;
```

Is this considered an OK thing to do or is there a better way?
Thanks!

Question is different from the one suggested as I'm specifically dealing with null values in the model.

Comment: It's *already* null. You don't need to reinitialize it to null

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you give a C# Auto-Property a default value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40730/how-do-you-give-a-c-sharp-auto-property-a-default-value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do already:

```
public double? Distance { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Creating a nullable model is enough.

`public double? Distance { get; set; }`

Answer (score 1):

You can use nullable. By using '?' after the datatype you can make it nullable.

```
public double? Distance { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

the best way is to set the value to null where you are creating the object of model instead of assigning null initially .`

```
YourClass objectName = new Yourclass();

objectName.Distance = null;
```

may be i am wrong but when you initialize an object if it has nullable prop it is taken as null initially unless you dont assign a value