# Is there a way to optimize adding to a list with the same values?

Tags: c#

There are several objects I have to add to a list that contain the same information—I would like to know a way how I can optimize the problem. See code below.

"GroupNumber" and "IsAvailable" are all going to be the same.

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        List<ClassA> listAs = new List<ClassA>();
        listAs.Add(new ClassA() {GroupNumber = 1, Name = "PersonA", IsAvailable = true});
        listAs.Add(new ClassA() {GroupNumber = 1, Name = "PersonB", IsAvailable = true});
        listAs.Add(new ClassA() {GroupNumber = 1, Name = "PersonC", IsAvailable = true});
    }
}

public class ClassA
{
  public int GroupNumber {get; set;}
  public string Name {get; set;}
  public bool IsAvailable {get; set;}
}
```

I want to know if there is a shortcut where I could add only "Name" with leaving "GroupNumber" and "IsAvailable" the same.

```
listAs.Add(new ClassA() {Name = "PersonA"});
listAs.Add(new ClassA() {Name = "PersonA"});
listAs.Add(new ClassA() {Name = "PersonA"});
```

Comment: You can use a loop.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you give a C# Auto-Property a default value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40730/how-do-you-give-a-c-sharp-auto-property-a-default-value)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. But you can create a method which reduces the amount of duplication:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
    List<ClassA> listAs = new List<ClassA>()
    {
        CreateAvailablePerson("PersonA"),
        CreateAvailablePerson("PersonB"),
        CreateAvailablePerson("PersonC"),
    };
}

private static ClassA CreateAvailablePerson(string name)
{
    return new ClassA() { GroupNumber = 1, Name = name, IsAvailable = true };
}
```

If you're using C# 7.0+, you can use a [local function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/local-functions) to get rid of the extra class-level method

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
    List<ClassA> listAs = new List<ClassA>()
    {
        Create("PersonA"),
        Create("PersonB"),
        Create("PersonC"),
    };

    ClassA Create(string name) => new ClassA() { GroupNumber = 1, Name = name, IsAvailable = true };
}
```

If the default state for your `ClassA` is to be available, for example, you can also initialize it to `true` by default:

```
public class ClassA
{
    public int GroupNumber { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsAvailable { get; set; } = true;
}
```

Then you can do `new ClassA() { GroupNumber = 1, Name = name }`. You can of course also do this for `GroupNumber`, if its normal value is `1`.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to the other answers, use default arguments in your constructor:

```
public class ClassA
{
    public int GroupNumber {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public bool IsAvailable {get; set;}

    public ClassA(string name, int groupNumber = 1, bool isAvailable = true)
    {
        Name = name;
        GroupNumber = groupNumber;
        IsAvailable = isAvailable;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can create a constructor with 1 parameter, and set the other fields by default some value you desire.

```
 public ClassA (string name){
      GroupNumber = 100,
      Name = name,
      IsAvailable = true
}
```

if you want to have different GroupNumber values, **initialize a static variable** inside the class with some value, and in the constructor you will increment it.

Answer (score 1):

Use a special class called 'factory' like this:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace Solution
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
            var factory = new ClassAFactory(groupNumber: 1, isAvailable: true);
            var listAs = new[] { "PersonA", "PersonB", "PersonC" }
                               .Select(name => factory.CreateClassA(name))
                               .ToList();
        }
    }

    public class ClassA
    {
        public int GroupNumber { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool IsAvailable { get; set; }
    }

    public class ClassAFactory
    {
        private int GroupNumber { get; }
        public bool IsAvailable { get; }

        public ClassAFactory(int groupNumber, bool isAvailable)
        {
            GroupNumber = groupNumber;
            IsAvailable = isAvailable;
        }

        public ClassA CreateClassA(string name)
        {
            return new ClassA { GroupNumber = GroupNumber, Name = name, IsAvailable = IsAvailable };
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set a default value

```
public class ClassA
{
  public int GroupNumber {get; set;} = 1;
  public string Name {get; set;}
  public bool IsAvailable {get; set;} = true;
}
```

Comment: It will fork only for this 2 hard-coded values. If there is any change you should do the same as in question.