# Is having a lot of properties initiated at instantiation a good practice?

Tags: c#, oop, constructor

I have a Cart class that has a lot of properties:

```
public class Cart
{
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
    public Products Products { get; set; }
    public Payments Payments { get; set; }
    public DateTime TimeOfArrival { get; set; }
    //...and so on
}
```

Whenever I want to instantiate a new `Cart`, I need to initiate these properties. Some of them are already known (e.g. Customer), others not yet (e.g. Products and Payment). So this is what I ended up doing this when I instantiate a new ticket:

```
Cart Cart = new Cart
                    {
                        // for know properties:
                        Customer = currentCustomer,
                        TimeOfArrival = DateTime.Now,

                        // for properties that are going to be filled later:
                        Products = new List<Product>(),
                        Payments = new List<Payment>(),

                        // ...and so on
                    };
```

This solution obviously works but seems very bulky at instantiation, plus there's a lot of work done in initiator which I assume is a bad thing.

Am I doing this right or is having a lot of properties initiated at instantiation not a good practice ? If so, how should I do it ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are not doing anything wrong, this is not a lot..

Comment: Nothing wrong per se. Indeed setting up defaults for your properties is a good practice. You can shorten your code though with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40730/how-do-you-give-a-c-sharp-auto-property-a-default-value This will remove the need of repeating lines of code when you initialize your objects

Comment: Why cant the Cart class instantiate those objects in the ctor?  Eliminates the need for the consumer to do so in order for anything to work correctly.

Comment: @Aldert @Steve Thanks for your quick answers, there are actually a handful of other properties which I spared you though I believe it doesn't change much. The problem is the constructor won't let me set `new List<Thing>()` as default parameter value in the constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is room for improvement. But be careful, a lot depends on requirements, and basically they should be leading in a lot of cases. And it's a matter of taste. Some people are more puristic than others.

It depends on your project: how important is it? Is it a side project or your core business?

And, yes there is room for improvement; there always is... now, next year, at every review... etc. Just saying: there is no perfect design.

---

Now, my strongly biased opinion : )

Your setup represents a typical case in a domain  driven design. I'll send a link later.

In general, in domain driven design you try to determine a specific business functionality/concept, and wrap this in, preferably a most descriptive object. Basically you are on the right track with your cart.

But, it seems the cart has just a bit to much domain knowledge in it.

Specifically the nested complex types can be an indication that you are crossing some domain boundaries.

For example: the `customer` ; which is situated within the cart. The customer might in its turn contain an address. ... and so on.

Clearly one's address is irrelevant for the cart itself.

Also; payment. I dont think its typically bound to a cart, maybe more to an order.

As for the products; a small description and a link to the actual product would suffice. Next to the obvious price and quantity ofcourse.

For a cart, you might want to consider to store a customer ID only, and fetch the customer if additional data is required.

Anyhow, it's a though subject in general. The best advise is to; not try to involve too much complex types, and only put in your model the thing that only makes sense to that specific "thing"

Comment: Thank you for your very inspiring answer. I'm actually trying to make a UWP registering app for my own (very small) business, though it doesn't have to be very sophisticated.

Comment: Cool :-) ... a bonus: if you're UWP, its definitely worth to checkout the MVVM pattern : )

Comment: I'm already on it ! coming from data science I feel like I'm discovering a brand new world in oop.

Answer (score 2):

Use a constructor:

```
public class Cart
{
    // shorthand constructor, only 1 setting, else use a normal function style constructor
    public Cart (Customer cust) => Customer = cust;

    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
    public Products Products { get; set; } = new List<Product>();
    public Payments Payments { get; set; } = new List<Payment>();
    public DateTime TimeOfArrival { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
    //...and so on
}

var cart = new Cart( my_customer_instance );  // all thats needs to be done
```

This is easier then the `Lazy<...>` approach if you only develop something for your own business. Lazy rocks if you have *costly* things to create that might or might not be needed at all. Empty lists do not cost you much - you could even go as far as creating them with 0 elements if you are really concerned (They'll increase internal buffer if you "feed" them).

The big advantage is that you do not *care* what to do if you need a `new Cart(customer)` - the class handles initialization itself.

Comment: I'm definitely going to use that approach, I didn't know about this way of defining default values for properties.

Answer (score 1):

If you are worried about the cost of initializing properties up front (which, in this case, doesn't look like a problem), then you can use `Lazy<T>` to conveniently instantiate the properties when they are needed.

For example

```
private Lazy<List<Product>> products;
constructor() {
   products = new Lazy<List<Product>>(()=>new List<Product>());
} 
public List<Product> Products => products.Value;
```

For something like a list, this is pretty silly, but for a more expensive intializating, `Lazy<T>` can be useful.

Comment: Not really what I was looking for but good to know, thanks !
Actually my Product class is quite heavy so might be useful in the future.